# How to add mysql jdbc drivers in servlet web app in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, servlets, jdbc

I'm using servlet in intellij idea and mysql jdbc. and I have added mysql connector in my project (i.e File->Project Structure ->Libraries) and am still facing the error seems that the intellij cannot find the mysql drivers

[image]

**Here is the error I'm facing..**

```
`No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbc-db
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.example.studentapp.HelloServlet.doPost(HelloServlet.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)`
```

Comment: Make sure IntelliJ IDEA has drivers to connect to the database: https://i.imgur.com/DsmJJir.png

Comment: Also, make sure the driver is added to libraries and to the build path

Comment: If you are using Gradle/Maven, add the appropriate dependency to build.gradle/pom.xml

Comment: yes i have already added the driver to the library but how do i add to the build path?

Comment: Do you use Maven/Gradle?

Comment: I'm using maven

Comment: In a web application, you shouldn't use `DriverManager`, use a `DataSource`. However, your problem is likely one of the driver not being on the initial classpath, but on the web-application classpath. In that case, you will have to explicitly load the JDBC driver with `Class.forName` to register it with `DriverManager`. Also, if you use Maven, the appropriate way to add dependencies is through the Maven pom.xml.